# Find 3D concave hull based on original model and convex hull

Tags: geometry, 3d, computational-geometry

I want to find the concave hull of a 3d model, with a threshold for the maximum edge size. Googling around let me to the following approach (mainly abstracting from 2d approaches):

- Determine the convex hull of the model
- Select the longest edge of the convex hull if any above threshold
- Remove this edge by repacing it by to edges to a vertex on the original model
- Continue until no edge has length above threshold

Now I got stuck with determining which vertex to select from the original model. Any ideas on this?

Both the original model and the convex model can be used as inpunt. I could recreate the original. This would happen if the threshold is 0.

The purpose is to predict the space and material that the model would take in my 3D printer. If the model has holes, or small cavings this space should be taken with the model. How big that hole may be to make it not usefull is determined by the threshold.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited the question based on it. I think I can recreate the original, but maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: No, it was me who misunderstood the OP. Just to clarify, why doesn't the original model satisfy the requirements? Or perhaps you want to optimize something while keeping the edges short?

Comment: Edited the question to answer you.

Comment: In 2D that would be easier, in 3D I would perhaps use the 3D equivalent of [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) (for me the easiest way to calculate it was via convex hull of 4D paraboloide). Unfortunately I cannot give any justification, only that it often happens to have good properties from computer graphics perspective.